# How to use the output of running a which command in vscode launch.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I would like to use the output of running `which brownie` as the value for `"program"` in a `launch.json`. E.g. in this snippet of `launch.json`

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Brownie: run deploy.js",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "/home/fanta/.local/virtualenv/python3.10/bin/brownie",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "args": ["run", "scripts/deploy.js"]
    },
```

I would like to replace the full path that I have hard-wired `/home/fanta/.local/virtualenv/python3.10/bin/brownie` with the output of `which brownie`. How can I do that?

Comment: why don't you activate the python environment with the brownie you want

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a `preLaunchTask` that executes the `which brownie` and writes it to a temp file

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "which brownie",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "which brownie > /tmp/brownie-loc.txt"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) you can use the command `extension.commandvariable.file.content` to use the file content in the launch

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Brownie: run deploy.js",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${input:browniePath}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "args": ["run", "scripts/deploy.js"],
      "preLaunchTask": "which brownie"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "browniePath",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
      "args": {
        "fileName": "/tmp/brownie-loc.txt"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```